# Como puedo obtener mi IP pública en Next.JS

Tags: javascript, nextjs, ip

Tengo un proyecto en Next 12 y tengo un componente con un contador de visitas. Este contador de visitas intenta obtener la IP del usuario. El tema es que una vez en producción, el contador no avanza y creo que es porque esta tomando IPs locales (`127.0.0.1` por ejemplo).

En la API donde analizo esa info, tengo esto

```
const HandleCondoViewers = async (req, res) => {
  const publicIP = req.connection.remoteAddress;
  ...
```

Y al parecer `req.connection.remoteAddress` no me sirve para obtener la IP pública.

Hay alguna forma "nativa" de Next o de JavaScript para obtener la IP pública sin instalar dependencias? De no ser asi, que dependencia me recomiendan para este caso?

Comment: Existe [`request-ip`](https://github.com/pbojinov/request-ip) que podes utlizar. Si quiseras saber como lo hace, basta con [ver el código](https://github.com/pbojinov/request-ip/blob/master/lib/index.js#L39)

Comment: Muchas gracias @Marcos! lo estoy probando y en local funcionó como dice la documentación. Vamos a ver luego que pasa en producción. En lugar de ir al `middleware` directamente importé la libreria en mi API y asigné `const publicIP = requestIp.getClientIp(req);`, debería estar bien, verdad?

Comment: Hola M.G, si al final resulta que te funciona, recorda que podes responder a tu propia pregunta. Compartir tu solución puede ayudar a otros en el futuro. Respecto a tu pregunta, si, así esta perfecto.

Comment: @Marcos antes de probarlo en producción intente crear un archivo en Stackblitz y la IP me devuelve `null`, ya sea desde la API o desde `getServerSideProps`. No se si es normal en este tipo de plataformas, pero cuando pueda mandar el deploy te cuento.